# How to get multiple documents in mongoDB using ids in an array?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

I am trying to fetch multiple documents from a MongoDB database using currently this code:

```
var ids = ["0d54350a-22d3-4902-96c3-dbf4570fe1e7", "8ee78634-d7e7-44c2-bb63-4cc3424c6b59", "91350d7e-0465-4442-9e72-d690eede56a8", "ed8c2224-9832-4724-9631-a47d34691c9c", "9844c814-5288-42cd-8c30-e4222ece5023", "c7000b94-7610-4fb6-b27d-56b85ea5e30e"];

const result = await myModel.find({ uuid: {$in: ids } }, {_id: 0});
```

Well, this works fine BUT only if the length of **ids** isn't bigger than 35. (There is no error, but if it's bigger than 35 the request times out)
I want to query for more than 35 ids at once as fast as possible.

Comment: How big are the documents? How many are you trying to get? Is there an index on uuid? You might need to batch it or use a cursor.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/TekmZXfLrv9 I'm not really sure why 35 is such a big deal? Do you not get any errors when you use 34?

Comment: I don’t get any errors even when it is bigger than 35 the request just times out. The documents are very small and  the query is really only about 100 uuids.